# Shrink one of the disks in a multi device BTRFS filesystem

Tags: linux, raid, filesystems, software-raid, btrfs

My root partition is running out of space and I have no other SATA slots. I have a BTRFS raid0 and I would like to shrink one of the partitions I used for the BTRFS-raid0 and add it to the root partition (make it raid0). How can I do that?

The layout is as follows:

- /dev/sda

  - sda1 - 500M    - EFI  - /boot
  - sda2 - 10G     - Root - /
  - sda3 - 455.3G  - btrfs-raid0-disk0 - /data
- /dev/sdb - 465.8G - btrfs-raid0-disk1 - /data
- /dev/sdc - 931.5G - btrfs-raid0-disk2 - /data
- /dev/sdd

  - sdd1 - 465.8G - btrfs-raid0-disk3 - /data

Now, I want to shrink /dev/sdd1 from 465.8G to 410G, create /dev/sdd2, combine /dev/sda2 and /dev/sdd2 using btrfs raid0 and use it as root.

**In Short:**
How can I shrink one of the partitions in a btrfs multi device (raid0) filesystem.

Comment: Please don't mind my wonky / unsafe configuration. I use the server and the raid to store mostly AOSP source code and the server hardware is close to junk. I don't mind losing any of them. At the same time, I would like to shrink the raid0 without data loss.

Comment: either you don't care and use all space and have a data loss strategy or you care and don't do such activities. please decide. However I am not want to write like a moral apostles. the nearest solution might be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75120/how-can-i-resize-and-shrink-a-btrfs-partition)

Comment: @djdomi. The whole raid is about 2.5 TB. It is filled up to 2 TB. I don't care if my hard disk fails and I have to re download the data. But, I don't want to delete the data myself shrink the disk. And the link you attached shows answer to shrinking a btrfs file system and doesn't say anything about multi device volumes. I added the previous comment just so that people would stop advising me about the problems of raid 0.